# catkin_make fails weirdly after trying to create a new package

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, viso2-ros, image-pipeline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to build a new package in a catkin_workspace.
After trying to build this package everything seems to be malfunctioning.
E.g. if i delete the package under construction and only leave one surely working package in my
catkin_ws (e.g. image_view, viso2_ros) i still get the following errors when doing catkin_make.

.......

```
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package cv_bridge.

  Set cv_bridge_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for cv_bridge.  The file will have one of the following names:

    cv_bridgeConfig.cmake
    cv_bridge-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  viso2-hydro/viso2_ros/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package image_geometry.

  Set image_geometry_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for image_geometry.  The file will have one of the following names:

    image_geometryConfig.cmake
    image_geometry-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  viso2-hydro/viso2_ros/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- checking for module 'openni-dev'
--   package 'openni-dev' not found
-- checking for module 'openni-dev'
--   package 'openni-dev' not found
-- checking for module 'openni-dev'
--   package 'openni-dev' not found
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
```

........

What the f** has happened.
Did my package under construction destroy anything?
Sidenote: I am a beginner to ROS!

Also here is my original CMakeLists.txt for my new package "stereo_setup":

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(stereo_setup)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include)

# set include directories for headers and libraries
include_directories($(stereo_setup_INCLUDE_DIRS), include, lib)

FIND_LIBRARY(FLYCAP_SDK NAMES libflycapture.so library
  PATHS /lib)

# set the executable for executing ROS cmds
add_executable(stereo_setup_exe src/stereo_setup.cpp)

#set the properties 
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(stereo_setup_exe PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME stereo_setup)


# add the sourcecode as a "library"
#add_library(stereo_setup src/stereo_setup.cpp)

# target; link against 
target_link_libraries(stereo_setup ${FLYCAP_SDK})

target_link_libraries(stereo_setup ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189686/catkin_make-fails-weirdly-after-trying-to-create-a-new-package/) by [mister_kay](https://answers.ros.org/users/18994/mister_kay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2014-08-11**:
Which version of ROS are you using? Do you install it correctly? I use "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-desktop-full" to install my ROS groovy and I can "roscd" those two packages you mention. Maybe you should add them into package.xml, or maybe you should source setup.bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to install image_geometry package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-image-geometry
```

(replace indigo with the ros version you're using).

Concerning the fact that `catkin_make` still fails after deleting your package, try removing `workspace/devel` and `workspace/build` if you want to build from a clean environment.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on 2016-02-22**:
Hi, I use ROS Indigo too and I have the same problem, but image-geometry is installed in my computer. It appears only when I want to declare the node as a CPP library (not if executable). Any idea?